# background color every other row in SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm using Ruby on Rails.
I have a .sass file for a datagrid.
I'd like every other row to have a different colored background.

I tried this:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) 
    background-color: #E3E3E3
```

What should it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is generally what's used to every-other items:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#E3E3E3;
}
```

Comment: Jesse, that is how I do it in css - but, I'm asking about sass. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: You do things in SASS the same way you do things in CSS when you're just doing normal CSS things.

Answer (score 1):

For me that works:

```
[hauleth@NIUNIOBOOK] ~ $ sass
tr:nth-child(2n+1) 
    background-color: #E3E3E3
^D
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #e3e3e3; }
```

So what do you wanna get other?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a report.css.sass file.
The following isn't working to color every other row.
Maybe it's something else and not the sass syntax?

`body
  font-family: Times new Roman

table.datagrid
  border-collapse: collapse
  th
    background-color: #bfd0e6
    &.created_at
      min-width: 74px

  td 
    border: 1px solid black
    padding: 5px
    background-color: #ffffff
    &.ordered
      &.asc
        background-color: #bfd0e6
      &.desc
        background-color: #8ea9cc
 
  tr:nth-child(2n+1) 
    background-color: #E3E3E3`